# Pagination of HTML content using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am new to jQuery. In the below code, I am trying to do a pagination for each sub header, If i click sub header 1, the page should show only the content of sub header 1. I have already tried and got the number of pages that has to be created and got the index.

How can i create pagination ? Like in the below case, i want "1,2,3" to be displayed because there are three sub headers. And on clicking 1, i should show only sub header 1 and the others should be hidden. How can it be done using jQuery?

```
<span>Click a Header!</span>
<div><h2>Sub Header 1</h2></div><div>Content 1</div>
<div><h2>Sub Header 2</h2></div><div>Content 2</div>
<div><h2>Sub Header 3</h2></div><div>Content 3</div>

$("h2").click(function () {
    // this is the dom element clicked
    var index = $("h2").index(this);
    var size = $("h2").size(this);
    $("span").text("That was Header index #" + index + "   Total Pages #" + size);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/GtDHW/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
$("h2").click(function () {
    $("h2").not(this).parent().next().hide();
    $(this).parent().next().show();
});
```

Explanation:

- Take all the `H2`s, except the clicked one, go to parent (`DIV` containing the `H2`s), get next element (`DIV` with content), hide all the `DIV`s containing content
- Take the clicked `H2`, traverse in the similar manner, make sure the `DIV` with content is shown

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be what you're trying to do, hopefully in a more organized approach.

If you're trying to chunk text (like news stories or whatnot), there's plugins out there that can help smooth that over. You just need to do some research and find what's appropriate for what you're needing.

Some examples include:

- [Easy Paginate](http://cssglobe.com/post/9801/easy-paginate-jquery-plugin-for-pagination)
- [jPaginate](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/17/jpaginate-a-fancy-jquery-pagination-plugin/)
- [Sweet Pages](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/05/sweet-pages-a-jquery-pagination-solution/)

Note, pagination also refers to [table data pagination](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/pagination), and to a [lesser degree listmaking](http://th3silverlining.com/2010/04/15/pajination-a-jquery-pagination-plugin/). So be aware when you go looking to make sure you're specific, or you might find some odd results. Also be aware that many times pagination occurs at the server, although that's not required. Some "new media" sites do load the entire article and then toggle between screens, a la The Daily Beast.

**HTML**

```
<div id="msg">Click a Header to Show Associated Content</div>
<div class="story">
    <h2>Sub Header 1</h2>
    <div>Content 1</div>
</div>
<div class="story">
    <h2>Sub Header 2</h2>
    <div>Content 2</div>
</div>
<div class="story">
    <h2>Sub Header 3</h2>
    <div>Content 3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.story > div {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $headers = $(".story h2"),
        $msg = $('#msg');

    $headers.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            $content = $headers.not(this).siblings('div'),
            msg = "Select story #" + $this.text();

        $content.hide();

        $this.siblings('div').show();

        $msg.text(msg);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/GtDHW/1/