# Paginate a page with more than one table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

I have a JSP page which will be filled with dynamically created tables with data filled in from a database.

This page will look something like this

```
<div id="VehicleWrap">
   <form id="bookvehicle" method="post" action="bookvehicle">
       <table>
           <tr>
              <td class="label"><label id="lbodytype" for="transmission">Body Type</label></td>
              <td class="field"><input id="bodytype" name="bodytype" type="text" value="<%= vehicle.getBodyType()%>" maxlength="50" readonly/></td>
              <td class="status"></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td class="label"><label id="ltransmission" for="transmission">Transmission</label></td>
              <td class="field"><input id="transmission" name="transmission" type="text" value="<%= vehicle.getTransmission()%>" maxlength="50" readonly/></td>
              <td class="status"></td>
           </tr>
       </table>

       <table>
           <tr>
              <td class="label"><label id="lbodytype" for="transmission">Body Type</label></td>
              <td class="field"><input id="bodytype" name="bodytype" type="text" value="<%= vehicle.getBodyType()%>" maxlength="50" readonly/></td>
              <td class="status"></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td class="label"><label id="ltransmission" for="transmission">Transmission</label></td>
              <td class="field"><input id="transmission" name="transmission" type="text" value="<%= vehicle.getTransmission()%>" maxlength="50" readonly/></td>
              <td class="status"></td>
           </tr>
       </table>

       <table>
           <tr>
              <td class="label"><label id="lbodytype" for="transmission">Body Type</label></td>
              <td class="field"><input id="bodytype" name="bodytype" type="text" value="<%= vehicle.getBodyType()%>" maxlength="50" readonly/></td>
              <td class="status"></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td class="label"><label id="ltransmission" for="transmission">Transmission</label></td>
              <td class="field"><input id="transmission" name="transmission" type="text" value="<%= vehicle.getTransmission()%>" maxlength="50" readonly/></td>
              <td class="status"></td>
           </tr>
       </table>
   </form>
</div>
```

As you can see above I will have a list of tables within a form and div. However i cant form the tables into one long table and use one of the many table pagination plugins.

How would i paginate this so that for example, there would only be 5 tables to a pagination page.

Comment: What have you tried? Why you can't use the pagination plugins? why you don't format the table the way a pagination plugin would work for your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexipage is a [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) plugin for paginate any HTML content. Inspired
in [Quick Paginate](http://projects.allmarkedup.com/jquery_quick_paginate/) plugin.

#### Usage

To use the flexipage plugin, include jQuery and jquery.flexipage inside the  tag of your document:

```
<script src="javascripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascripts/jquery.flexipage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then write some HTML like this:

```
<div>
  <ul class="fp-example">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    ...
    <li>Item 22</li>
    <li>Item 23</li>
    <li>Item 24</li>
    <li>Item 25</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And start flexipage

```
$('.fp-example').flexipage();
```

---

Also, see these resources:

- [10 jQuery pagination plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/)
- [Creating Modern jQuery Pagination for Content](http://www.script-tutorials.com/creating-modern-jquery-pagination-for-content/)
- [Pagination of HTML content using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081716/pagination-of-html-content-using-jquery)
- [Easy Paginate](http://cssglobe.com/post/9801/easy-paginate-jquery-plugin-for-pagination)
- [jPaginate](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/17/jpaginate-a-fancy-jquery-pagination-plugin/)
- [Sweet Pages](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/05/sweet-pages-a-jquery-pagination-solution/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast reply, although what i really need is a way to paginate a collection of individual tables. So for example their will be 10 tables on a page and i want to divide those tables up so only 5 appear on a page.

Comment: Ah... Gimme a moment, I will change the answer. :)

Comment: @user667430 Can you please check the answer?